# How to convert string object to object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I'm using typescript and I'm receiving a value with object format, but it's a string.

Lets call it as: `myVar`.

`MyVar` have this value (image below) as string.

```
const string myVar = '{"value":"1"}'
```

How can I transform this string to object for access your value?

[image]

Comment: JSON.parse(string)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const myVar: string = '{"value":"1"}'
const myVarObj = JSON.parse(myVar)
console.log(myVarObj)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwGoEMBOAuG00EswDmMAvDAOQDeARAG4oA2ArgKZUZUCMVAvmQFChIsRKjQB5AEYArEjABSAZTEA5AHQAHdBGYAKEegCUA8BBD1mq+iAJ7k6SVKNA)

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
JSON.parse('{"value": "1"}');
```